# Using a Non-Const String as a CategoryAttribute Name

Tags: c#, properties, resources, attributes, constants

All, I am localising my C# application and I have come to my settings control. As I am using a `PropertyGrid` I am using properties to provide the options. I have a `CategoryAttribute` for "Server Access" I need to show in different languages - I had:

```
[CategoryAttribute("ServerAccess"),
 ReadOnlyAttribute(false),
 XmlElement,
 DescriptionAttribute("Message about the Server Access Option.")]
public bool ShowSystemDatabases 
{
    get { return this.showSystemDatabases; }
    set { this.showSystemDatabases = value; }
}
```

and I attempted to change this to:

```
[CategoryAttribute(ObjectStrings.SettingsServerAccess),
 ReadOnlyAttribute(false),
 XmlElement,
 DescriptionAttribute(MessageStrings.SettingsShowSystemDatabaseInfo)]
public bool ShowSystemDatabases 
{
    get { return this.showSystemDatabases; }
    set { this.showSystemDatabases = value; }
}
```

Where `ObjectStrings` is my resource file ('ObjectStrings.resx' et al.). This is throwing a compile-time error

```
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array 
creation expression of an attribute parameter type...
```

clearly I can't use a string when the constructor is expecting a `const string`. I have tried casting from `string` to `const string` using various round-the-houses method but all have failed. it is a simple enough issue, but...

**What is the easiest way around this problem?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You just can't achieve this. You need to bring from resources into const literals inside source code. Attributes only allow constant values and `Type`

Comment: Okay, so how can I localise the description of my properties in the property grid at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you could handle this especially in the case of control's attributes, but a general way to achieve this is to make Resources resolved at runtime, using parameters like these on your attribute :

```
MessageResourceType = typeof (MyResource), MessageResourceName = "MyResourceKey")
```

instead of directy passing the pointer to resource key.

I don't know if there is an equivalent way for CategoryAttribute, DescriptionAttribute and others Controls' properties attributes, or if there is a way to overload them.